# PL/SQL Create procedure which returns two string values

Tags: sql, plsql, procedure

I am new to SQL and am trying to create a procedure which takes in a 6 character string eg. 'POLICE' and then will return two substring values eg. 'POL', 'ICE'

This is what I have tried so far:

```
procedure split_string(inputString in string, substr1 in OUT string, substr2 in OUT string)
is
begin
      substr1 := SUBSTR(inputString, 1, 3);
      substr2 := SUBSTR(inputString, 4, 3);
end split_string;
```

However this is not working, i am also unsure on how to call this function and use its values elsewhere in the code.

Is it something like this:

```
split_string('POLICE') ?
```

Comment: You will have to pass substr1 and substr2 place holders too. Use `split_string('POLICE',substr1,substr2);`. You can then use substr1 and substr2 as these will have updated values because of the procedure call. Of course, use VARCHAR2 as shown in answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
CREATE OR replace procedure split_string(inputString in varchar2, 
                                         substr1  IN OUT varchar2, 
                                         substr2  IN OUT varchar2
                                         )
As

begin
      substr1 := SUBSTR(inputString, 1, 3);
      substr2 := SUBSTR(inputString, 4, 3);
END split_string;
```

Usage:

```
DECLARE
   a   VARCHAR2 (10);
   b   VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   split_string ('POLICE', a, b);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (a || ',' || b);
END;
```

Output

```
SQL>     

    POL,ICE

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Okay that seems fine. How would I use this procedure elsewhere? I want to call it inside another procedure it looks like this:

Comment: procedure get_date(inputString in string, cRslts out ResultsCursor)
is
begin
    open cRslts for
         select distinct column_name
         from table n
         where n.column1 in (SUBSTR(ccyPair, 1, 3), SUBSTR(ccyPair, 4, 3))
end get_date;

Comment: OK THANKS, that is fine